# Express: Different ways to assign parameter to app.use()

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

What is the difference between:

```
app.use('my-directory', express.static(join(__dirname, 'my-directory');
```

and

```
app.use(express.static(join(__dirname, 'other-directory'));
```

The both seem to do the same if I'm not wrong.

In the first case I specify a file-path and the second case the name of the directory becomes the file-path.

**What is the difference between the two variations?**

Comment: No, they are not same

Comment: In how far do they differ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app.use('my-directory', express.static(join(__dirname, 'my-directory');
```

is a middleware used with a path mounted it 
and there is not path mounted for

```
app.use(express.static(join(__dirname, 'other-directory'));
```

That means that the `express.static` middleware executes at every request.

Lets suppose there is a file `foo.html` in both `my-directory` and `other-directory`.

In the first case you would find that file at path `/my-directory/foo.html` and in the second case you would find it at path `/foo.html`.

Answer (score 1):

The first optional parameter to `app.use` specifies a base path to which the middleware will be applied. See the docs here; [app.use](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.use)

When you dont specify this first parameter the middleware will be applied to all requests, regardless of its path.

They seem to do the same thing in your case but in fact, in your first case `express.static` will never be invoked if your path does not start with `my-directory`.